# Optimize MySQL search Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I just tried to do some small search for my website to find user entries and sort them in a logical way, I tried improving the results, but it ended up with a way too big query string, which takes 14 seconds to execute on my Server. So I'm currently wondering how to optimize the query without any bigger changes in the result.

Here is my current query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT 1 as m_rank,title,rank, content, url, keywords FROM websites
        WHERE title LIKE '".$search."'
            union all
    SELECT 2 as m_rank,title,rank, content, url, keywords FROM websites
        WHERE title LIKE '".$search."%'
        OR title LIKE '%".$search."'
            union all
    SELECT 3 as m_rank,title,rank, content, url, keywords FROM websites
        WHERE title LIKE '%".$search."%'
            union all
    SELECT 4 as m_rank,title,rank, content, url, keywords FROM websites
        WHERE keywords LIKE '".$search."'
            union all
    SELECT 5 as m_rank,title,rank, content, url, keywords FROM websites
        WHERE keywords LIKE '%".$search."'
        OR keywords LIKE '".$search."%'
            union all
    SELECT 6 as m_rank,title,rank, content, url, keywords FROM websites
        WHERE keywords LIKE '%".$search."%'
            union all
    SELECT 7 as m_rank,title,rank, content, url, keywords FROM websites
        WHERE content LIKE '".$search."'
            union all
    SELECT 8 as m_rank,title,rank, content, url, keywords FROM websites
        WHERE content LIKE '%".$search."'
        OR content LIKE '".$search."%'
            union all
    SELECT 9 as m_rank,title,rank, content, url, keywords FROM websites
        WHERE content LIKE '%".$search."%'
    ) a
    ORDER BY m_rank, rank DESC LIMIT ".$page.", ".$max;
```

Are there also possibilities to cut the query using PHP for pre-processing?

Comment: Other alternatives to perhaps look into: `FULLTEXT` searches (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) or implementing something like Apache Lucene (http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) rather than an RYO solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with one query.  Put the different search conditions in a `case` to assign `m_rank`.  Something like:

```
SELECT title, rank, content, url, keywords,
       (case when title LIKE '".$search."' then 1
             when title LIKE '".$search."%' OR title LIKE '%".$search."' then 2
             when title LIKE '%".$search."%' then 3
             . . .
             else NULL
        end) as m_rank
FROM websites
HAVING m_rank is not null
ORDER BY m_rank, rank DESC
LIMIT ".$page.", ".$max;
```

Comment: nice - using `CASE` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) is much neater than some of the `IF` behemoths I've written in the past :)